# Overlay of two imshow plots on top of each other, with a slider to change the opacity of the layer

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

The code below works to overlay two `imshow` plots, and to create a slider which changes the value of the global variable `OPACITY`.

Unfortunately, `img1.set_data(y); fig.canvas.draw_idle()` doesn't redraw the new opacity.

**How to make an overlay of two `imshow` plots with a slider to change the opacity of the 2nd layer?**

[image]

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib.widgets as mpwidgets

OPACITY = 0.5

x = np.random.random((100, 50))
y = np.linspace(0, 0.1, 100*50).reshape((100, 50))

# PLOT
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [5, 1]})
img0 = ax0.imshow(x, cmap="jet")
img1 = ax0.imshow(y, cmap="jet", alpha=OPACITY)

def update(value): 
    global OPACITY
    OPACITY = value
    print(OPACITY)
    img1.set_data(y)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

slider0 = mpwidgets.Slider(ax=ax1, label='opacity', valmin=0, valmax=1, valinit=OPACITY)
slider0.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-set the opacity of the overlaying `img1` within the `update` function by [`img1.set_alpha()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html?highlight=set_alpha#customizing-your-objects):

[image]

[image]

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib.widgets as mpwidgets

OPACITY = 0.5

x = np.random.random((100, 50))
y = np.linspace(0, 0.1, 100*50).reshape((100, 50))

# PLOT
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [5, 1]})
img0 = ax0.imshow(x, cmap="jet")
img1 = ax0.imshow(y, cmap="jet", alpha=OPACITY)


def update(value): 
    img1.set_alpha(value)    
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

slider0 = mpwidgets.Slider(ax=ax1, label='opacity', valmin=0, valmax=1, valinit=OPACITY)
slider0.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer and the answer from [Overlay of two layers of different shapes with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73971674/overlay-of-two-layers-of-different-shapes-with-matplotlib), here is a full example with opacity slider + plots of different shapes:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib.widgets as mpwidgets, scipy.misc
x = scipy.misc.face(gray=False)     # shape (768, 1024, 3)
y = np.random.random((100, 133))    # shape (100, 133)
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [5, 1]})
OPACITY = 0.5
img0 = ax0.imshow(x, cmap="jet")
img1 = ax0.imshow(y, cmap="jet", alpha=OPACITY, extent=img0.get_extent())
slider0 = mpwidgets.Slider(ax=ax1, label='opacity', valmin=0, valmax=1, valinit=OPACITY)
slider0.on_changed(lambda value: img1.set_alpha(value))
plt.show()
```