# Multiple imshow on the same plot, with opacity slider

Tags: python, numpy, plotly, plotly-python

With Plotly, I'd like to display two `imshow` on the same page, at the same place, with opacity.

This nearly works:

```
import plotly.express as px, numpy as np
from skimage import io
img = io.imread('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Crab_Nebula.jpg/240px-Crab_Nebula.jpg')
fig = px.imshow(img)
x = np.random.random((100, 200))
fig2 = px.imshow(x)
fig.show()
fig2.show()
```

but it displays the two `imshow` images in two different tabs.

**How to display the two "imshow" on the same plot, with an opacity slider for both layers?**

For reference, here is the `matplotlib` equivalent:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib.widgets as mpwidgets, scipy.misc
x = scipy.misc.face(gray=False)     # shape (768, 1024, 3)
y = np.random.random((100, 133))    # shape (100, 133)
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [5, 1]})
OPACITY = 0.5
img0 = ax0.imshow(x, cmap="jet")
img1 = ax0.imshow(y, cmap="jet", alpha=OPACITY, extent=img0.get_extent())
slider0 = mpwidgets.Slider(ax=ax1, label='opacity', valmin=0, valmax=1, valinit=OPACITY)
slider0.on_changed(lambda value: img1.set_alpha(value))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the requirements. Say, the slider value is `v`. Would you like both images to have the opacity `v`, or maybe one will have the opacity `v`, the other `1-v`? Also, in your snippet `y` will appear on top of `x` - should it remain like this for all values of `v`?

Comment: @YuliaV `v` for one and `1-v` for the other would be perfect (in my case I did slightly differently - one was always displayed with opacity `1` - but here it doesn't matter).

Comment: @YuliaV in my example `y` was on top, but when opacity is near 0, it vanishes. Any combination that allows the user to go from one imshow to the other smoothly (with opacity) would be perfect.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @Hamzah the script is not run inside an IDE (I'm not using Jupyter for this precise application, it is a standalone app), it is run with `python myscript.py`.

Comment: Even with   . py file you can run ipywidgets. Please look at this https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2622

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overlay of two imshow plots on top of each other, with a slider to change the opacity of the layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73951076/overlay-of-two-imshow-plots-on-top-of-each-other-with-a-slider-to-change-the-op)

Comment: @matanster not at all, your link is about matpltotlib/numpy, here it's about *plotly*, which is totally different ;) I suggest to remove the close vote, because here it's misleading, since plotly and numpy+matplotlib have two very different dataviz API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by the OP, since `opacity` is a style attribute applied by the client regardless of the trace (data) which is associated to a given image, there is no need to precompute one trace for each image variation, nor to redraw anything when the slider moves.

Using [simple slider controls](https://plotly.com/python/sliders/), we should be able to apply such (minor) changes in real-time.

---

**Option 1 :**

The first option is to let Plotly.js handle the changes by specifying the proper `method` and `args` in the slider' [`steps`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/sliders/#layout-sliders-items-slider-steps) configuration (ie. using the [restyle](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrestyle) method, Plotly is smart enough to *not* redraw the whole plot) :

```py
from PIL import Image
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc

imgA = scipy.misc.face()
imgB = Image.fromarray(np.random.random(imgA.shape[:2])*255).convert('RGB')

fig = go.Figure([
    go.Image(name='raccoon', z=imgA, opacity=1), # trace 0
    go.Image(name='noise', z=imgB, opacity=0.5)  # trace 1
])

slider = {
    'active': 50,
    'currentvalue': {'prefix': 'Noise: '},
    'steps': [{
        'value': step/100,
        'label': f'{step}%',
        'visible': True,
        'execute': True,
        'method': 'restyle',
        'args': [{'opacity': step/100}, [1]]     # apply to trace [1] only
    } for step in range(101)]
}

fig.update_layout(sliders=[slider])
fig.show(renderer='browser')
```

---

**Option 2 :**

The second option demonstrates a more general case where one wants to bypass Plotly API on slider events and trigger his own code instead. For example, what if the restyle method were not efficient enough for this task ?

In this situation, one can hook into the [plotly_sliderchange](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/components/sliders/draw.js#L421) event and apply the changes manually in order to obtain smooth transitions.

The browser (default) renderer makes it possible by using the [`post_script`](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.html#plotly.basedatatypes.BaseFigure.to_html) parameter, which you can pass to the `show()` method. It allows to add javascript snippets which are executed just after plot creation. Once one knows that (documentation should emphasize this part!), it is just a matter of binding the appropriate handler. For example (JS syntax highlighting) :

```js
// {plot_id} is a placeholder for the graphDiv id.
const gd = document.getElementById('{plot_id}');

// Retrieve the image (easier with d3, cf. 1st revision, see comments)
const trace = gd.calcdata.find(data => data[0].trace.name === 'noise')[0];
const group = Object.keys(trace).find(prop => (/node[0-4]/).test(prop));
const img = trace[group][0][0].firstChild;

// Listen for slider events and apply changes on the fly
gd.on('plotly_sliderchange', event => img.style.opacity = event.step.value);
```

Now for the [slider configuration](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/sliders/#layout-sliders-items-slider-steps-items-step-execute), the important thing is to set `execute=False` and `method='skip'` to bypass API calls and prevent redrawing the plot when the slider changes :

```py
slider = {
    'active': 50,
    'currentvalue': {'prefix': 'Noise: '},
    'steps': [{
        'value': step/100,
        'label': f'{step}%',
        'visible': True,
        'execute': False,
        'method': 'skip',
    } for step in range(101)]
}

js = '''
    const gd = document.getElementById('{plot_id}');
    const trace = gd.calcdata.find(data => data[0].trace.name === 'noise')[0];
    const group = Object.keys(trace).find(prop => (/node[0-4]/).test(prop));
    const img = trace[group][0][0].firstChild;
    gd.on('plotly_sliderchange', event => img.style.opacity = event.step.value);
'''

fig.update_layout(sliders=[slider])
fig.show(renderer='browser', post_script=[js])
```

Comment: Your code does not work. I think you missed something.

Comment: When I play with the slider, the noise is unchanged.

Comment: You're right, I was running an outdated version of plotly and didn't notice that [d3 is not exported anymore with the API](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/commit/c71d68966db2fd25e0f923f59ac8377a2d751c23#diff-8ab41fe13597e1554b5d6b4c227b5f123ff2d6726a7f3688a8b8d1224fe1d4f3) :/ so retrieving the proper image element among several images having no id and without making assumption is a bit less easy (ie. which image belongs to which trace, as we can't assign DOM id to them from Python). I'm fixing the code so that d3 is not required. Thanks for pointing this out !

Comment: Have you updated your code?

Comment: @Hamzah I just did.

Comment: But why did you select the render to be a browser instead of the default renderer?

Comment: Because "_explicit is better than implicit_". Any renderer could be set as default but not all of them allow for interactions driven by javascript code, and the OP mentioned he doesn't use notebooks.

Comment: @EricLavault Would you know how to convert your first code block into full Plotly.JS solution? Here is a beginning but I don't know how to add the two traces: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359950/two-heatmaps-on-top-of-each-other-with-opacity-with-plotly-js

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that pre-computing all traces is an essential step to create the `layer.Slider` in Plotly as documented [here](https://plotly.com/python/sliders/). Therefore, we want to compute the only required trace `on the fly` rather than pre-computing all traces upfront. Moreover, I totally agree with you that it is ineffective solution to build all traces in advanced on the user machine because this will take long time and consume huge amount of memory, especially if the image has large size.

From my perspective, I see the best option is to use both `Plotly` and `ipywidgets` and doing this will save much more time and memory in compared to the first option. In the solution below, I update the only trace with the selected opacity by the user interactively.

**Full Code**

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from skimage import io 
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from ipywidgets import FloatSlider, VBox

img = io.imread("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543349689-9a4d426bee8e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=801&q=80")
noise = np.random.random(img.shape[:2]) 


fig = go.FigureWidget(px.imshow(img))

fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=noise, opacity=0.0, 
                         showscale=False, colorscale ="Greys",
                         name = "noise"))

def update(value):
    fig.update_traces(opacity=value["new"],selector=({'name':'noise'}))

Opacity_slider = FloatSlider(value=0.0,min=0.0,max=1.0,
                             step=0.1, description='Opacity:')

Opacity_slider.observe(update, names="value")

vb = VBox((fig, Opacity_slider))
vb.layout.align_items = 'center'
display(vb)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For my application, I don't use Jupyter notebooks but only Plotly. Or maybe can we use Jupyter Widget in the middle of a Plotly dashboard, without using a Jupyter notebook? Would you have an example code to update the opacity in realtime with `layout.slider`?

Comment: @Basj try to use `animation_frame` as in https://plotly.com/python/imshow/

Comment: @Basj but you should create the noisy image with different opacities as frames and feed it to the px.imshow to get the slider.

Comment: I guess we can compute it in realtime (=when the slider moves), because if we should send to the web client *all* variations of the noisy image, that's a lot of unnecessary data (255x the normal amount of data). Would you have an example of code with slider, without JupyterLab?

Comment: Would you have an example code with a slider, without precomputing everything? Usually with a slider, we compute new data on the fly.

Comment: Only 2 frames are needed. The opacity of the images can be directly controlled with a slider with steps like: 
`steps = [dict(method='restyle', args=['opacity', [1.0, i and i/10]]) for i in range(11)]`

Comment: Hi @Basj , if you run my code with single value of opacity, you will find that it takes long time to show the image. Therefore, you cannot build your image with a slider without any delay. You will find that during tuning the value of opacity through the slider, it will take long time to show the noisy image and that undesirable behavior from the user perspective.  Therefore, I recommend pre-computing the traces upfront, however, you can build your trace “noisy images” on the fly.

Comment: Thanks @Hamzah. Your current code doesn't run in a script `python app.py`: `NameError: name 'display' is not defined`. How to run it outside Jupyter? `display` is only available in IPython, is that right? (`from IPython.display import display`), how to use it with browser renderer?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is uses little memory and works very quickly. Although it does use a heatmap rather than a second imshow, the end result is the same.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from skimage import io 

img = io.imread('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Crab_Nebula.jpg/240px-Crab_Nebula.jpg')
x = np.random.random((len(img), len(img[0])))

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Image(z=img))

for step in np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1):
    fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=x,
                 showscale=False,
                 opacity=step))

for n in range(1, len(fig.data)):
    fig.data[n].visible = False

fig.data[6].visible = True

steps = []
for i in range(1, len(fig.data)):
    step = dict(
        method = 'restyle',
        args = ['visible', [False] * len(fig.data)],
        )
    step['args'][1][0] = True
    step['args'][1][i] = True
    steps.append(step)
sliders = [dict(
    active=5,
    steps=steps
    )]

fig.layout.sliders = sliders
fig.show()
```

[image: Fig]

Comment: Thanks! It works but there is a 1-delay latency after each slide click.