# Two heatmaps on top of each other with opacity with Plotly.JS

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm trying to port [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74317122/1422096) to a 100% Plotly.JS solution.
TL;DR : how to have two heatmaps on top of eacher with an opacity slider, with Plotly.JS (no Python)?

Beginning of solution, but how to add the second trace?

```js
const z = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++)
  z.push(Array.from({ length: 600 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)));
const data = [{ z: z, colorscale: "YlGnBu", type: "heatmap" }];
const steps = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
  steps.push({ label: i + "%", execute: true, method: "restyle", args: [{ opacity: i / 100 }] });
const layout = { sliders: [{ name: "slider", steps: steps, active: 100 }] };
Plotly.newPlot("graph", data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

---

For reference: original Python solution:

```
from PIL import Image
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc

imgA = scipy.misc.face()
imgB = Image.fromarray(np.random.random(imgA.shape[:2])*255).convert('RGB')

fig = go.Figure([
    go.Image(name='raccoon', z=imgA, opacity=1), # trace 0
    go.Image(name='noise', z=imgB, opacity=0.5)  # trace 1
])

slider = {
    'active': 50,
    'currentvalue': {'prefix': 'Noise: '},
    'steps': [{
        'value': step/100,
        'label': f'{step}%',
        'visible': True,
        'execute': True,
        'method': 'restyle',
        'args': [{'opacity': step/100}, [1]]     # apply to trace [1] only
    } for step in range(101)]
}

fig.update_layout(sliders=[slider])
fig.show(renderer='browser')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second trace goes into the `data` array as well. The thing to note is that indexing matters : the trace at index 1 is drawn above the trace at index 0, and so on.

For the slider configuration, it should be the same as in python : each step change triggers the same 'restyle' method with the same arguments, ie. `Plotly.restyle(graphDiv, ...args)`, that is, with [`args`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/sliders/#layout-sliders-items-slider-steps-items-step-args) such that the method call matches the [signature](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrestyle) :

```
Plotly.restyle(graphDiv, update [, traceIndices])
```

Now, the most important thing is *which trace* (traceIndices) the slider should target, that is, which *index* or which *name* for explicitly named traces (default is *all* if I'm not wrong), but again here it doesn't change between Python and Javascript.

Here is a full example (play around with it on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/lvlte/pen/oNMOXbE)) :

```js
// Random z data
const w = {length: 600};
const h = {length: 400};
const z0 = Array.from(h, () => Array.from(w, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)));
const z1 = Array.from(h, () => Array.from(w, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)));

// Initial opacity for the trace 'above' 
const op_init = 0.5;

const data = [
  // Nb. Trace 1 drawn on top of trace 0
  {type: 'heatmap', z: z0, colorscale: 'Greys'},                    // trace 0
  {type: 'heatmap', z: z1, colorscale: 'Cividis', opacity: op_init} // trace 1
];

// Steps for the opacity slider
const steps = [];
const n_steps = 100; // number of steps above step 0
for (let i = 0; i <= n_steps; i++) {
  steps.push({
    label: i + '%',
    execute: true,
    method: 'restyle',
    args: [{
      opacity: i/n_steps
    }, [1]] // <- Nb. this applies only to trace 1
  });
}

const layout = {
  width: 600,
  sliders: [{
    steps: steps,
    active: Math.round(op_init * n_steps), // slider default matches op_init 
    pad: {t: 30},
    currentvalue: {prefix: 'opacity: '}
  }]
};

Plotly.newPlot('plot', data, layout);
```

---

**Image vs Heatmap**

A Heatmap works only with single channel data (individual value-to-color mappings according to a given colorscale).

When working with rgb (or rgba, rgba256, hsl, hsla), one has to use the [`image`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/image/) type. The difference is that `z` *must be* a 2-dimensional array in which each element is an array of 3 or 4 numbers representing a color (the `colormodel` should be set accordingly).

For example, setting an rgb image made of noise as the background layer :

```js
const z0 = Array.from(h, () => Array.from(w, () => ['r', 'g', 'b'].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)) ));

// ...

const data = [
  {type: 'image', z: z0, colormodel: 'rgb'},                        // trace 0
  {type: 'heatmap', z: z1, colorscale: 'Cividis', opacity: op_init} // trace 1
];
```

Here a second example where we have an rgb[a] image (DOM object `img`) and its pixel data represented as a 1-dimensional Uint8Array (`uint8Arr`), which need to be converted in 2d :

```js
const z0 = [];
const nChannels = uint8Arr.length / img.width / img.height;
const chunkSize = uint8Arr.length / img.height;
const z0_model = nChannels === 4 ? 'rgba' : 'rgb';

for (let i = 0; i < uint8Arr.length; i += chunkSize) {
  const chunk = uint8Arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
  const row = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < chunk.length; j += nChannels)
    row.push(chunk.slice(j, j + nChannels));
  z0.push(row);
}

// ...

const data = [
  {type: 'image', z: z0, colormodel: z0_model},                     // trace 0
  {type: 'heatmap', z: z1, colorscale: 'Cividis', opacity: op_init} // trace 1
];
```

---

Nb. When you plot an image, the yaxis is automatically reversed (unless specified otherwise, which would display the image upside down). This affects the orientation of the heatmap y-labels, as they're on the same plot, but only the labels not the data.

Here is the layout settings ensuring that both traces share the same aspect ratio and that the image is oriented correctly :

```js
const layout = {
  // ...
  xaxis: {anchor: 'y', scaleanchor: 'y', constrain: 'domain'},
  yaxis: {anchor: 'x', autorange: 'reversed', constrain: 'domain'},
};
```

Comment: Thanks again @EricLavault for your answer! Would you have an idea for this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75697331/heatmap-and-image-layers-on-top-of-each-other-with-plotly? I'm now super close to what I was looking for :)